# shared prefrence stored value not working with in android onCreate()

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

In my application i am using shared preferences its working fine within onResume() only its not working within onCreate(). Anybody know the reason? in onCreate that shared preference value always null only.

here my code

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {

    setTextValues();
    super.onResume();
    }

private void setTextValues(){       
      txt1.setText(PreferenceConnector.readString(this,PreferenceConnector.MILEAGE, null));
      txt2.setText(PreferenceConnector.readString(this,PreferenceConnector.YEAR, null));
      txt3.setText(PreferenceConnector.readString(this,PreferenceConnector.CAPACITY, null));         
}

   package com.InternetGMBH.Sample.Utilities;

     import com.InternetGMBH.Tample.Activities.WheelActivity;

     import android.content.Context;
      import android.content.SharedPreferences;
     import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;

  public class PreferenceConnector{
  public static final String PREF_NAME = "PEOPLE_PREFERENCES";
  public static final int MODE = Context.MODE_PRIVATE;


public static final String MILEAGE= "MILEAGE";
public static final String YEAR= "YEAR";
public static final String CAPACITY= "CAPACITY";



public static void writeBoolean(Context context, String key, boolean value) {
    getEditor(context).putBoolean(key, value).commit();
}

public static boolean readBoolean(Context context, String key, boolean defValue) {
    return getPreferences(context).getBoolean(key, defValue);
}

public static void writeInteger(Context context, String key, int value) {
    getEditor(context).putInt(key, value).commit();

}

public static int readInteger(Context context, String key, int defValue) {
    return getPreferences(context).getInt(key, defValue);
}

public static void writeString(Context context, String key, String value) {
    getEditor(context).putString(key, value).commit();

}

public static String readString(Context context, String key, String defValue) {
    return getPreferences(context).getString(key, defValue);
}

public static void writeFloat(Context context, String key, float value) {
    getEditor(context).putFloat(key, value).commit();
}

public static float readFloat(Context context, String key, float defValue) {
    return getPreferences(context).getFloat(key, defValue);
}

public static void writeLong(Context context, String key, long value) {
    getEditor(context).putLong(key, value).commit();
}

public static long readLong(Context context, String key, long defValue) {
    return getPreferences(context).getLong(key, defValue);
}

public static SharedPreferences getPreferences(Context context) {
    return context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, MODE);
}



public static Editor getEditor(Context context) {
    return getPreferences(context).edit();
}
```

}

if i call setTextValues() within onCreate() it display null value only. but onResume its working fine.

Comment: What is this PreferenceConnector? Is it something you have written? If yes, can u show the code?

Comment: Where is the onCreate implementation?

Answer (score 1):

It seems your activity is first Activity of your application, in onCreate method SharedPreferences might not initialized properly.

Its best to use Preferences in onStart method, instead of onCreate or onResume method.

Answer (score 0):

SharedPreferences is different from preferences. You should be calling getSharedPreferences like the sample code below:

```
public static String APP_PREFERENCES = "appPreferences";
public static String PREFERENCE_SAMPLE = "prefSample";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //get Shared preferences
    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(APP_PREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE);

    //retrieve a preference
    String str = sharedPreferences.getString(PREFERENCE_SAMPLE, "");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this as shared prefrence class

```
public class PreferenceConnector{
public static final String PREF_NAME = "PEOPLE_PREFERENCES";
public static final int MODE = Context.MODE_PRIVATE;

/*public static final String NAME = "NAME";
public static final String SURNAME = "SURNAME";
public static final String AGE = "AGE";*/

public static void writeBoolean(Context context, String key, boolean value) {
    getEditor(context).putBoolean(key, value).commit();
}

public static boolean readBoolean(Context context, String key, boolean defValue) {
    return getPreferences(context).getBoolean(key, defValue);
}

public static void writeInteger(Context context, String key, int value) {
    getEditor(context).putInt(key, value).commit();

}

public static int readInteger(Context context, String key, int defValue) {
    return getPreferences(context).getInt(key, defValue);
}

public static void writeString(Context context, String key, String value) {
    getEditor(context).putString(key, value).commit();

}

public static String readString(Context context, String key, String defValue) {
    return getPreferences(context).getString(key, defValue);
}

public static void writeFloat(Context context, String key, float value) {
    getEditor(context).putFloat(key, value).commit();
}

public static float readFloat(Context context, String key, float defValue) {
    return getPreferences(context).getFloat(key, defValue);
}

public static void writeLong(Context context, String key, long value) {
    getEditor(context).putLong(key, value).commit();
}

public static long readLong(Context context, String key, long defValue) {
    return getPreferences(context).getLong(key, defValue);
}

public static SharedPreferences getPreferences(Context context) {
    return context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, MODE);
}

public static Editor getEditor(Context context) {
    return getPreferences(context).edit();
}
```

}

Comment: You can write using 'PreferenceConnector.writeString(settings.this,"pwd", temp_cp);'and read using 'pwd=PreferenceConnector.readString(settings.this, "pwd","");'